# sensitive information required for docker build

Tags: maven, docker

For running docker build of my Java application I need sensitive information (a password to access the nexus maven repository).

What is the best way to make it available to the docker build process?

I thought about adding the ~/.m2/settings.xml to the container but it lies outside of the current directory/context and ADD is not able to access it.

UPDATE: in my current setup I need the credentials to run the build and create the image, not when running the container later based on the created image

Comment: Like @Evgeny said you should build image without sensitive information, then mount the sensitive data to docker by mount volume when you `run` the image.

Comment: the thing is that I need the sensitive information when running the build and creating the image, not when running the container later

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into [mounting a volume from HOST into the container](http://docs.docker.io.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/use/working_with_volumes/)

Comment: as far as I know mounting a volume is not possible while building a docker image

Comment: @ThomasEinwaller Your question needs to be clearer. Do you need to credentials in order to download files during the build or when the container is running?

Comment: @ThomasEinwaller that's correct - to maintain Docker image portability it is only possible when running a container off of an image.